# Fire ResizeEvent in GWT (Google Web Toolkit)

Tags: events, gwt, resize

On my site I have a number of Google Maps (v3) that you can select via a TabPanel (one per tab) but there is a problem when you switch tabs. When you select the tab it does not "wake up" the map. To fix this I simply need to use ResizeEvent.fire(**source**, Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHight()); this will active the resize listener on the map and "wake it up."  My problem is that I cant get a pointer to the registered resize handlers for the browser window (it is package protected in com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.handlers) therefore I don't know what to use as my source. If anyone has the answer to my solution or another possible solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply but I figured out that these three lines:
`HasLatLng center = mapWidget.getMap().getCenter();`
`Event.trigger(mapWidget.getMap(), "resize");`
`mapWidget.getMap().setCenter(center);`
do the trick. This is basically what happens when the map loads initially. In the onLoad() method for MapWidget it makes a call to super.onLoad() then executes these three lines which "wakes up" the map and preserves the center point.

Comment: Can't find Event.Trigger. Pls have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543276/trigger-resize-event-to-google-maps-from-gwt-2-5-using-gwt-maps-3-8-0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if using resize is the best way of doing this (I haven't embedded a map before), but you could consider using a TabLayoutPanel instead of a TabPanel, and call panel.[onResize()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html#onResize%28%29) instead of firing the resize event. Note that you would need to use *[LayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html)s (or something that implements [ProvidesResize](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html)) all the way to the root of the document, and your page would need to be rendered in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GWT-Maps-V3-Api](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api), there is a `triggerResize()` function in the `MapWidget` class that does the trick.