# second call of google maps does not show the map in correct size

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

using gwt-maps-3.8.0 i display a route in a gwt popup. Works when called once but does not work on second call.

What should i do ... some advice to refresh the mapWidget?
[image: defect map]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you display the map, trigger its `resize` event.

From the documentation:

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454535/fire-resizeevent-in-gwt-google-web-toolkit) the way to do this in GWT is

```
Event.trigger(mapWidget.getMap(), "resize");
```

At the moment, the map has zero size as far as the API is concerned, so it's just displaying the buffer of tiles around the single pixel at (0,0). Triggering the `resize` event causes the API to get the correct size from the browser so the right tiles are fetched for display.

Comment: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') : is not available in gwt-maps-3.8.0

Comment: @Malte I found a question which addresses the difference between the GWT implementation and native Javascript.

Comment: seams that the lib i am using changes everything: eg. there is not mapWidget.getMap() and instead of "HasLatLng center = mapWidget.getMap().getCenter();" it is "LatLng center = mapWidget.getCenter();" this is the source: goo.gl/mYqbj

Comment: If what was `mapWidget.getMap().` is now just `mapWidget.`, then you could try `Event.trigger(mapWidget,"resize");`. Basically, you need to trigger an event on the map. That must be documented somewhere!

Comment: tried that but "import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;"
-> Event.trigger(mapWidget,"resize"); 
"The method trigger(GoogleMap, String) is undefined for the type Event"

Comment: I can't find `.trigger` either ([Docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html)) but that is what you need to do. You may need another question to ask how to trigger an event in GWT. I'm not a GWT guru.

Comment: When resizing the browser the map is adjusted. Thanks Andrew, i will try to find out how to trigger this.

Comment: @Malte There is an easy way to trigger the resize with gwt-maps-3.8.0 `mapWidget.getMap().triggerResize()`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (map shown in a popup; reload the popup and the map was no longer centered). 
In the end I managed to fix my problem using the triggerResize method from the GoogleMap class. However it worked only after I triggered this method from an Idle event. 
triggerResize will notify the map to show the correct tiles.
setCenter will make sure the map is centered once again.

```
gMap.addIdleListenerOnce(new IdleHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle() {
        gMap.triggerResize();
        gMap.setCenter(myLatLng);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [GWT-V3-Maps-API](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) it would be done as follows for a case where a div or window resizes:

```
    /*
     * Example of how to dynamically resize the map to fit the window - add
     * your events
     */
    Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
            MapHandlerRegistration.trigger(mapWidget, MapEventType.RESIZE);
            GWT.log("Window has been resized!");
        }
    });

    mapWidget.addResizeHandler(new ResizeMapHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(ResizeMapEvent event) {
            GWT.log("Map has been resized!");
        }
    });
```