# trigger resize Event to Google Maps from GWT 2.5 using "gwt-maps-3.8.0"

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

Using **gwt-maps-3.8.0** [lib GWT-Maps](http://goo.gl/mYqbj) and i am not able to trigger a resize.

-> tried using "import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;" -> `Event.trigger(mapWidget,"resize");` "The method trigger(GoogleMap, String) is undefined for the type Event"

(this is the follow up from here: [second call of google maps does not show the map in correct size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530334/second-call-of-google-maps-does-not-show-the-map-in-correct-size))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the best I found so far:

```
private final native void resizeMap(GoogleMap map) /*-{
    $wnd.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use your own nativ JS code you could just use the `mapWidget.getMap().triggerResize()` method provided by the gwt-maps-3.8.0 library

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. I also had to reset the center.