# How to trigger map event on Google Maps < v3

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I'm having an issue with an app that loads several google maps. Second of this maps has the famous issue of not displaying well because it seems the div dimensions are not found correctly. I've checked the proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454535/fire-resizeevent-in-gwt-google-web-toolkit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530334/second-call-of-google-maps-does-not-show-the-map-in-correct-size). None of the proposed solutions work for me because I cannot switch to v3 right now, I'll do some time later on, but can't do it right now.

Thus, how can I trigger the resize event on google maps API < v3? I've tried this already:

```
HasLatLng center = mapWidget.getMap().getCenter();
Event.trigger(mapWidget.getMap(), "resize");
mapWidget.getMap().setCenter(center);
```

But my MapWidget class has no getMap() method, besides I don't have an Event class that allows passing a MapWidget and String as arguments.

Lastly, I've also tried this proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543276/trigger-resize-event-to-google-maps-from-gwt-2-5-using-gwt-maps-3-8-0):

```
private final native void resizeMap(GoogleMap map) /*-{
    $wnd.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}-*/;
```

But this does not work either...any clues?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GWT, but it appears that mapWidget already is a pointer to the MapWidget-instance.

Maybe  [`checkResizeAndCenter()`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/com/google/gwt/maps/client/MapWidget.html#checkResizeAndCenter%28%29) is what you are looking for. At least the description sounds promising:

> *Notifies the map of a change in the size of its container and moves to the center of the map. Call this method after the size of the
>   container DOM object has changed, so that the map can adjust itself to
>   fit the new size.*

```
mapWidget.checkResizeAndCenter();
```

Comment: This seems to work, shame I couldn't find this method earlier...thanks Molle, correct answer :)